# How to define a variable, when multiple variables are being called from one button

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu, undefined

I am able to return my first variable, however the second returns as undefined...any suggestions

here is my code:

```
function myFunction2(id, id2)
{
var target = document.getElementById('criteria_selected');
var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
var value2 = document.getElementById(id2).value2;
var myprint = '<input type="checkbox" value="'+value+',value2='+value2+'"/>'+value+' '+value2+' </br>';
$(target).append(myprint);  
}
```

level_completed and match_percentage1 are id's for 2 different drop-down boxes

```
<input type="button" name="add_level" value="Add" onclick="myFunction2('level_completed','match_percentage1');">
```

here is my php code in criteria_selected

```
                if (isset($level_completed) && isset ($match_percentage1))
            {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $level_completed,&nbsp&nbsp,$match_percentage1 ?>"> 
                    <?php echo $level_completed,&nbsp&nbsp,$match_percentage1 ?> 
                    </br>';
            }
```

I am trying to return the value as one checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

value2 is not a property of elements, use value.

```
var value2 = document.getElementById(id2).value2;
```

Comment: nice catch - copy paste carelessness :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery, simple and better.

```
function myfunction(id,id2){

var value=$('#id').val();
var value2=$('#id2').val();

}
```

Comment: You should not use jQuery for simple tasks. The overhead of loading an entire library is simply not worth it. Even for cross browser support, if you know precisely who you are targeting and what you are doing, writing the bare necessary code for the specific thing you need accomplished is by far better than using jQuery.